# Shading Editor - View texture map in Node?

Tags: shaders

I thought there was an addon to do this, but maybe it's built in to blender 3.2 ?
In the Shading Editor, How to View texture preview image? A thumbnail version of whatever map is being used.

Comment: There are addons such as the one mentioned in one answer or [this one](https://blendermarket.com/products/node-preview) which is a more general preview but expensive. There are currently no plans by the foundation to add a general preview. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;TR

There is no native to preview a texture in the Shader Editor that I am aware of. There is an add-on for it though, as you mentioned. Perhaps [this](https://blendermarket.com/products/image-node-preview) is the one you were thinking of. Unfortunately it is commercial aka a paid product.

However, there are two other different methods that are both native and allow the previewing of an imported texture.

## Method 1

1. After you have assigned a texture to an Image Texture node, you can click on the browse file icon.

[image]

2. When the File Browser Editor opens up, if you have not already, enable <kbd>Display Mode - Thumbnails</kbd> as your preferred file preview choice. While the File Browser will unfortunately *not* snap to the location of your imported texture, it should however snap to the file-path location of where the imported texture is at on your local hard-drive.

[image]

## Method 2

View your imported texture in the <kbd>UV Editor</kbd> by simply clicking and selecting your texture via the highlighted dropdown menu.

[image]